# Magento - get the company name of a registred customer

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value, magento-1.4

I use this code:

```
$customerCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
->addNameToSelect()
->addAttributeToSelect('email')
->joinAttribute('postcode', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
->joinAttribute('postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')          
->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');
```

How can I also get the company name of a registred customer ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check if the attribute name is really "company"

```
joinAttribute('company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```